# how to find a string already have the value in php

Tags: php, arrays, find

I have an string like

```
$string =19,17,1,2,19,17;
```

Here 19 and 17 occurred two times , how can i remove the occurring and it will comes should like

```
$string =19,17,1,2;
```

I have tried first convert the string to array and check the array using in_array ;but i duknow how could i produce the result;

```
$id = explode(',',$string );
    $a=array();

    foreach($id as $k){
        if (!in_array($string , $id))
            $a[]=$k;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = explode(',', $string);
echo implode(',', array_unique($array));
```

Output:

```
19,17,1,2
```